# Simple GStreamer Program Error on Crostini Debian

Tags: c, debian, gstreamer, crostini

I'm following the "Hello World" GStreamer tutorial from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html). I first installed GStreamer via `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev`, and I compile the program using `g++ -Wall gstreamer-hello-world.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0)` with no problem. I downloaded a sample ogg file from [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg), and run the program using `./a.out Sample.ogg`. The program outputs the error message: "One element could not be created. Exiting.". I can see at that point in the C program that 6 `GstElement` pointers are being checked. One of them is `NULL`: `sink`. The statement which tried to initialise `sink` is shown below:

```cpp
sink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");
```

I am working on the virtual machine running Debian available within ChromeOS (often called Crostini). I can run other programs on Crostini which play audio. For example, VLC works, and has "VirtIO SoundCard" listed as the Audio Device.

Comment: GStreamer consist of many plugins. You should install them too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```